# How to import talend build job in eclipse

Tags: java, mongodb, talend

I'm using TOS for ESB 6.3.0 and created one job with tRESTClient.
My Job is:
[image]
I've build the above job and created zip folder, then extracted the folder also.
Now am trying for import the job into eclipse. i can select the folder but i couldn't import.
How to import the talend build job into eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to export your job from talend and import it into a standard Eclipse. 
Talend studio is based on eclipse, and jobs built on talend can't be reworked in another studio.

Comment: i'm not export the job from talend. I was build the job and trying to import the job in eclipse.

Comment: Is this possible or not?

Comment: sorry I never tried this. If you selected "include java source file" when building the job in talend studio, then your zip file will contain the *.java files generated..perhaps you could use them in Eclipse directly.